# Find a record which has multiple occurrences?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've a table like this

```
Acode  Bcode

100     4
101     3
100     8
105     4
105     8
104     1
109     8
110     3
109     8
```

I would like to find out Which are Acode belongs to more than one Bcode like
100 belongs to 4 as well 8 and 105 belongs to 4 as well 8 so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT Acode, COUNT(Bcode) 
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Acode
HAVING COUNT(Bcode) > 1
```

Comment: How will you display BCODE also?

Comment: @Nishanthi, I read it differently "I would like to find out Which are Acode belongs to more than one Bcode"

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT Acode,Count(Acode)
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY Acode 
HAVING Count(Acode) > 1
```

If you want to **find out Which are Acode belongs to more than one Bcode** then

Try this

```
SELECT T.ACode,T.BCode,S.Acode
FROM table1 T JOIN
(
  SELECT Acode,Count(Acode) As CCode
  FROM TABLE1
  GROUP BY Acode 
  HAVING Count(Acode) > 1
) As S ON S.ACode = T.ACode
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/190cc/3)**

*Output*

---

```
ACODE   BCODE
100     4
100     8
105     4
105     8
109     8
109     8
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. It should help. This will display both ACODE and BCODE

```
SELECT A.ACODE, A.BCODE
  FROM myTable A
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT B.ACODE
                 FROM myTable B
                WHERE B.ACODE = A.ACODE
                  AND B.BCODE <> A.BCODE );
```

If you need only ACODE and COUNT, then this would help:

```
SELECT ACODE, COUNT(BCODE) 
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY ACODE
HAVING COUNT(BCODE) > 1
```